# How to number the algorithms (some algorithms are put in a group)?

Tags: algorithms

I want to write some groups of algorithms. For example, there are 2 groups and 2 related algorithms in each group.

I do not know how to number every algorithm in this case (like 1.1.1, 1.1.2, 3.1.1, 3.1.2; the format is:

**number of section. number of group in the section. number of algorithm in the group.**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\setlength{\intextsep}{2pt}

\begin{document}

\section{A}
There is the first group of algorithm
\begin{figure*}[htbp]
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.49\textwidth}
    \begin{algorithm}[H]
      \begin{algorithmic}[1]
        \caption{$A_{1}\left( x_{1} \right)$}
        \STATE $y_{1} \leftarrow f\left( x_{1} \right)$
        \RETURN $y_{1}$
      \end{algorithmic}
    \end{algorithm}
  \end{minipage}
  \hfill
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.49\textwidth}
    \begin{algorithm}[H]
     \begin{algorithmic}[1]
        \caption{$A_{2}\left( x_{2} \right)$}
        \STATE $y_{2} \leftarrow f\left( x_{2} \right)$
        \RETURN $y_{2}$
      \end{algorithmic}
    \end{algorithm}
  \end{minipage}
\end{figure*}

Blah, blah, blah...
\section{B}
Blah, blah, blah...
\section{C}
There is the second group of algorithm
\begin{figure*}[htbp]
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.49\textwidth}
    \begin{algorithm}[H]
      \begin{algorithmic}[1]
        \caption{$C_{1}\left( x_{1} \right)$}
        \STATE $y_{1} \leftarrow f\left( x_{1} \right)$
        \RETURN $y_{1}$
      \end{algorithmic}
    \end{algorithm}
  \end{minipage}
  \hfill
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.49\textwidth}
    \begin{algorithm}[H]
      \begin{algorithmic}[1]
        \caption{$C_{2}\left( x_{2} \right)$}
        \STATE $y_{2} \leftarrow f\left( x_{2} \right)$
        \RETURN $y_{2}$
      \end{algorithmic}
    \end{algorithm}
  \end{minipage}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Added counter `algroup` and set counters to reset to zero automatically.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\setlength{\intextsep}{2pt}

\newcounter{algroup}[section]
\renewcommand{\thealgroup}{\thesection.\arabic{algroup}}
\counterwithin{algorithm}{algroup}
\renewcommand{\thealgorithm}{\thealgroup.\arabic{algorithm}}

\begin{document}

\section{A}
There is the first group of algorithm
\stepcounter{algroup}
\begin{figure*}[htbp]
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.49\textwidth}
    \begin{algorithm}[H]
      \begin{algorithmic}[1]
        \caption{$A_{1}\left( x_{1} \right)$}
        \State $y_{1} \leftarrow f\left( x_{1} \right)$
        \Return $y_{1}$
      \end{algorithmic}
    \end{algorithm}
  \end{minipage}
  \hfill
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.49\textwidth}
    \begin{algorithm}[H]
      \begin{algorithmic}[1]
        \caption{$A_{2}\left( x_{2} \right)$}
        \State $y_{2} \leftarrow f\left( x_{2} \right)$
        \Return $y_{2}$
      \end{algorithmic}
    \end{algorithm}
  \end{minipage}
\end{figure*}

Blah, blah, blah...
\section{B}
Blah, blah, blah...
\section{C}
There is the second group of algorithm
\stepcounter{algroup}
\begin{figure*}[htbp]
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.49\textwidth}
    \begin{algorithm}[H]
      \begin{algorithmic}[1]
        \caption{$C_{1}\left( x_{1} \right)$}
        \State $y_{1} \leftarrow f\left( x_{1} \right)$
        \Return $y_{1}$
      \end{algorithmic}
    \end{algorithm}
  \end{minipage}
  \hfill
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.49\textwidth}
    \begin{algorithm}[H]
      \begin{algorithmic}[1]
        \caption{$C_{2}\left( x_{2} \right)$}
        \State $y_{2} \leftarrow f\left( x_{2} \right)$
        \Return $y_{2}$
      \end{algorithmic}
    \end{algorithm}
  \end{minipage}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: What if there is an only one algorithm in chapter 2 whose number should be 2.1?

Comment: The only way I know is that I write "\renewcommand{\thealgorithm}{\thealgroup}" before that algorithm.